Python: how to pass the same lock to multiple threads mapped to a ThreadPoolExecutor?
Let's say I don't want to specify the lock globally. How can I pass the same lock to each thread within a ThreadPoolExecutor? Here's what doesn't work:
import threading
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def main():
    lock = threading.Lock()
    
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        executor.map(thread_function, range(10), lock)

def thread_function(number: int, lock: threading.Lock):
    with lock:
        print("Hello from the thread with argument: ", number)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

It says that the lock is not iterable. I thought there must be a way since objects in python are passed by reference, so if I could iterate over an object that always hands me a reference to the same lock that would probably work. But how to do it?

The lock is in the global namespace, you don't need to pass it at all.

executor.map(lambda n, lock=lock: thread_function(n, lock), range(10)) This also works if called in a function with a local lock variable.

@KlausD. Ops that was an oversight, I updated the description to reflect my problem better.

@MichaelButscher thx. There's no way without a lambda i suppose? Sorry for being picky

With from functools import partial you can also write it as executor.map(partial(thread_function, lock=lock), range(10)) but I don't see much gain in this variant.

You could make the Lock global but to answer your question I suggest:
from threading import Lock
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from itertools import repeat

def thread_function(number: int, lock: Lock):
    with lock:
        print("Hello from the thread with argument: ", number)

def main():
    lock = Lock()
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        executor.map(thread_function, range(10), repeat(lock))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Note that ThreadPoolExecutor doesn't support starmap However, if you use ThreadPool you could do it like this:
from threading import Lock
from itertools import repeat
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def thread_function(number: int, lock: Lock):
    with lock:
        print(f"Hello from the thread with argument: {number}")

def main():
    lock = Lock()
    with ThreadPool() as pool:
        for _ in pool.starmap_async(thread_function, zip(range(10), repeat(lock))).get():
            pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

